# Java annotation processor for type aliases

Tags: java, android, types, annotations, type-alias

For as long as I remember, I've always missed type aliases (e.g. typedefs in c++ or type/newtype in haskell) in Java.

In Android SDK, we've got [support annotations](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/support-annotations) which include `@IntDef`, `@StringDef` and various resource type annotations, which help us figure out possible misuse of integer/string values at compile time. I'm inserting a piece of code from the Android docs to give you the short idea:

```
@IntDef({NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface NavigationMode {}

public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;

@NavigationMode
public abstract int getNavigationMode();

public abstract void setNavigationMode(@NavigationMode int mode);
```

Actually, 95% of cases I want type aliasing are sort of same: when I got some kind of database row ID, usually `long` or `String`, which results in having to encode type information about the variable in name (e.g. `long folderId`, `long messageId`). However, there is an annoying limitation of `StringDef`/`IntDef` annotations: for some reason, they require a set of predefined constants, so you can only describe a finite set of values, which is obviously not enough for DB identifiers.

What I want is some kind of similar annotation say `@TypeAlias` and a Lint check, so I could do:

```
@TypeAlias
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface FolderId { }

@FolderId
public long getFolderIdByName(Database db, String name) {
    long id = db.foldersTable().findByName(name).getId();
    return id;
    /*
      we might need to suppress the check here
      (because we pass long as a @FolderId long),
      but that's okay, since we are aware of
      what we are doing here, and it's the only
      possible injection point for @FolderId
    */
}

public void deleteMessagesIn(Database db, @FolderId long folder) {
   // whatever
}

public void deleteMessagesInInbox(Database db) {
    deleteMessagesIn(db, 1); // rejected by Lint, trying to pass long as @FolderId long
    deleteMessagesIn(db, getFolderIdByName(db, "Inbox")); // ok, passes Lint check
}
```

I don't see any good reason for restricting type aliasing annotations to a set of finite values, we could just work around it by suppressing as I mentioned above, or maybe by introducing another annotation specifically for functions which provide type aliases.

What is more, this is not only about restrictions of the Android annotations: any plain Java application could benefit from these kinds of type aliases as well, and I didn't manage to google anything remotely similar. We could also benefit from using [TYPE_PARAMETER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE_PARAMETER) target, which will make all of it seem almost like real type aliases.

So the questions are:

- Are there static analyzers which implement these kinds of checks?
- If not, are there any fundamental limitations I am missing which prevent it from being implemented? Since again, I feel like this is very useful, so if there hadn't been any, someone would have done it.

P.S. @mernst pointed me at Checker framework, and I managed to integrate it with Android in a relatively painless way: https://github.com/karlicoss/checker-fenum-android-demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static analyzer that checks for correct use of type aliases (typedefs) is the [Fake Enum Checker](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#fenum-checker) that is distributed with the [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/).  It has been used to find bugs in Swing and JabRef.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not as convenient as I expected, but I made it work for Android project, awesome!